# R: Adding a name to a list item

Tags: r

In R, suppose I have defined the following list:

```
h <- list(rnorm(3),b="other things")
```

Now I would like to add the name `a` to the first item in the list, that is, to change the list `h` s.t. it becomes `h <- list(a=rnorm(3),b="other things")` where the instance of `rnorm(3)` stays the same. What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: `names(h)[1] <- "a"` ?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks! I was using the incorrect function `name` so it didn't work.

Comment: You can post that if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
names(h)[1] <- "a"
```

due to [David Arenburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001626/david-arenburg).